# PHP site crashes: Allowed memory size of xxx bytes exhausted

Tags: php, database, pdo

I'm currently setting up a php site and want to connect to a database. Whenever I call my dbconfig file I get the following error:

> [10-Jun-2019 04:45:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 5368709120 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8243113940412947600 bytes) in C:\inetpub\vhosts\test\mydomain.de\dbconfig.php on line 13

The database works and I get the data from it but when this error occours the whole site shuts down for a couple of minutes.

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "dbuser";
$dbname = "dbname";
$dbpassword = "dbpass";

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword);

$statement1 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id=1;");
$statement1->execute();

$result1 = $statement1->fetchAll();

foreach ($result1 as $row1)
{
    $language = $row1['lang'];
    $currency = $row1['currency'];
}
?>
```

> [10-Jun-2019 04:45:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 5368709120 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8243113940412947600 bytes) in C:\inetpub\vhosts\test\mydomain.de\dbconfig.php on line 13

Comment: you should `var_dump($row1['lang'])`  - see how much data it contains, also is this for only one row? If so, you should be using `->fetch()` which merely returns an array of that returned row data. Also passing `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` into `->fetch()` and `->fetchAll()` reduces your column count by half.. which also helps optimising

Comment: It only contains a single number. It also requests other rows.

Comment: in which case you should be using `->fetch()` a fetchAll and a foreach is super redundant here.

Comment: You said `Whenever I call my dbconfig file I get the following error:`, i am unable to see that calling code in your given code

Comment: I am tempted to blame Windows, just because i cannot think of any other explanation. The numbers shown are plainly weird. But just for clarity, what is the table structure for settings and what software versions you are using?

Comment: He just fetches to much data, if you have 500k rows with a lot of fields it is expected to run out of memory. A paging strategy could be the correct solution here.